# lscape rotates the whole document

Tags: rotating, landscape, revtex

I have been struggling with this for a couple of hours: Including the package [`lscape`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lscape) immediately rotates the whole document. I have no clue why it happens. The document is very simple:

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,preprint,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{lscape} 

\begin{document}
\title{}

\maketitle

\section{section 1}
A paragraph
\end{document}
```

Even with a `\begin{landscape}` environment the whole document is still changed.

Thank you ahead for any comments.

Comment: What is it that you're after exactly? I assume you want to control which pages are landscape and which ones are portrait?

Comment: There's seems to be a bad interaction between the `lscape` package and the `revtex4-1` document class. You could try using the `rotating` package instead of `lscape`. Sideways-set figures and tables can be created with the `sidewaysfigure` and `sidewaystable` environments, respectively.

Comment: @Wener, yes that is exactly what I wanted to do. I have a long table which needs to be shown in landscape.

Comment: @Mico, thank you for the suggestion. I guess you are right. I tried the "article" class and it works fine. I also tried sidewaytables, but it seems it does not support longtable. And ideas?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user2727768 - I didn't know you were looking to typeset a multipage table. AFAICT, the `sideways` environments cannot span multiple pages. :-(

Comment: @Mico, thank you anyway. I guess I would have to redesign my table

Comment: revtex explicitly tests for lscape being loaded and if so redefines some of its internal output routine commands, but then the behaviour is all wrong. It may be worth reporting it to the revtex maintainers. `revtex4-1.cls` has `\appdef\@outputpage@head{%
 \@ifx{\LS@rot\@undefined}{}{\LS@rot}%
}%`

Answer (score 4):

With Revtex 4-1, you have to use `turnpage` instead of `landscape`:

```
\begin{turnpage}
\begin{figure} or \begin{table}
[...]
\end{figure} or \end{table}
\end{turnpage}
```

Try this, it will work in almost all the cases

Comment: Thanks for this! Is it possible to have the turnpage also rotating the view by 90 degrees?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/643539/41144

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, revtex4-1 is known to not interact well with the lscape and pdflscape packages.  Would using the revtex4 instead be an option for you?

Note also that recent versions of the emulateapj class have a [revtex4] option that allows to work around the issue with lscape.

See also [this](http://newton.cx/~peter/2013/10/landscape-pages-emulateapj-and-arxiv/) article.

Comment: the same also happens with the `pdfpages` package and revtex4-1