# revtex and turnpage: also rotate the PDF page view by 90 degrees to the horizontal orientation

Tags: pdftex, packages, revtex

In the following revtex4, could we make the turnpage to also rotate the PDF page view by 90 degrees to the **horizontal** orientation (more than just rotating the content by 90 degrees but keeping the page the same **vertical** orientation)?

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}

\begin{turnpage}

\begin{figure} or 
\begin{table}

[...]

\end{figure} or \end{table}

\end{turnpage}
```

Other similar functions are:

```
\usepackage{lscape} 

\begin{landscape} 

\end{landscape}
```

Comment: your code doesn't compile. Always make a complete example.

Comment: Thanks - related question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133389/41144 but they do not turn the PDF by 90 degrees either.

Comment: sorry but I won't start a research project and wander through other links to understand your question and create a test document. Make your question complete.

Comment: Please clarify your question: you can rotate around the z-axis by a step of 90 degrees, on the x- and y-axis by 180 degrees. What rotation are you looking for?

Comment: The PDF file is only a 2-dimensional plane, so it is a 90-degree rotation that rotates the x-y plane of the PDF to the y-(-x) plane. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To restate the question as I understood it, since there seems to be some confusion in the comments: `revtex4` (`4-1` and `4-2`) provide the `turnpage` environment, which typesets the contents in landscape mode. However. the PDF still shows the landscape page in portrait orientation. You would like this page to not only be typeset in landscape mode, but also be shown in the same orientation.*

I managed to achieve this by means of some "magic code" I got from here: [Publish Landscape-oriented Tables With emulateapj on ArXiv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643539/revtex-and-turnpage-also-rotate-the-pdf-page-view-by-90-degrees-to-the-horizont). In particular, the relevant lines of code are the following:

```latex
[...]
\clearpage
\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}
[...]
```

This code results in that the pages after these two lines are typeset in landscape mode, while keeping pages before these two lines in portrait mode.
I haven't looked into *why* this macro works exactly (and if I do I'll update this answer), but this seems like enough to achieve the goal stated in the question. In particular, note that the `\clearpage` isn't critical -- I expect `\pagebreak` works just as well -- the point being that we can set the rotation for the PDF page by re-setting the `\pdfpageattr` macro before the page is shipped out.

Now, I looked at the definition of the `turnpage` environment (`\ShowCommand{\turnpage}`; `\endturnpage` does nothing), and we have:

```latex
\turnpage =
  \def \width@float  {\textheight}
  \def \widthd@float {\textheight}
  \appdef \@endfloatbox
  {
    \@ifxundefined \@currbox
      {\ltxgrid@warn {Cannot rotate! Not a float}}
    {
      \setbox \@currbox \vbox to\textwidth
      {\vfil \unvbox \@currbox \vfil}
      \global\setbox \@currbox \vbox
      { \rotatebox{90}{\box \@currbox} }
    }
  }
```

where whitespace is mine and for clarity. So, we have that the `sideways` environment is not doing anything too special, but rather setting a float the size of a page and adding some code to rotate the contents of the float. (Here, viz. `source2e` sec. P1.)

Assuming that this float will always get pushed to the next page (and I'm not completely sure how big of an assumption is this, but it's working for me in practice**), we can therefore get this float to display in landscape if we set `\pdfpageattr` properly at the beginning of the next page, and then reset the PDF orientation at the start of the page following.

I achieved this by leveraging the shipout hooks (viz. `lthooks-doc` and `ltshipout-doc`):

```latex
\appdef \turnpage {%
  % When we're declaring our turnpage float, instruct LaTeX to run
  % the following code after the current page has been finalized.
  \AddToHookNext{shipout/after}{%
    % Set the following page to be rotated by 90 degrees.
    \global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}%
    % Also, once this page is finalized (recalling that this is already
    % being called for the float's page), set the PDF attributes such that
    % the next pages are upright again.
    \AddToHookNext{shipout/after}{%
      \global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 0}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

I'm surprised at how robust (in the casual sense, not the LaTeX sense) this seems to be; it really hasn't broken at all in my document. Importantly, I'm using it together with a `table*` -- the asterisk is fundamental. Otherwise, even with an unmodified `revtex4`, the float's positioning is completely broken.

The usual caveats: I'm by no means a LaTeX expert (I've never bothered to read the TeX book, if that's any indication), so a lot of this comes from trial and error. Hopefully someone with a deeper understanding of TeX can correct any mistakes in my reasoning.

For clarity, here's how you would use this code in practice:

```latex
\documentclass{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Necessary to use turnpage!

\appdef \turnpage {%
  % When we're declaring our turnpage float, instruct LaTeX to run
  % the following code after the current page has been finalized.
  \AddToHookNext{shipout/after}{%
    % Set the following page to be rotated by 90 degrees.
    \global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}%
    % Also, once this page is finalized (recalling that this is already
    % being called for the float's page), set the PDF attributes such that
    % the next pages are upright again.
    \AddToHookNext{shipout/after}{%
      \global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 0}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

Start of the document...

\begin{turnpage}
\begin{table*}
  \caption{Caption of this table.}
  The contents of the table would go here.
\end{table*}
\end{turnpage}

...rest of the document

\end{document}
```

While testing this, I've found that it breaks if the page with the `turnpage` environment is the only page in the document.You can fix this quick-and-dirty by experimenting with using `shipout/before` instead of `shipout/after` in the `\appdef`. However, as long as there is some other content, it seems to work fine.

* Your question seems perfectly clear to me, to be honest. I'm unsure about the source of confusion.

** The one edge-case I can think of is when the `sideways` float is perfectly placed such that a `\pagebreak` already occurred naturally before it, and so the page *after* the `sideways` is rotated instead. I'm not sure this can actually happen -- testing it out by inserting a `\pagebreak` just before the float still yields good results -- but it should be easy to modify the code I've provided to deal with that specific case, if it ever happens.

Comment: the link https://newton.cx/~peter/howto/publish-emulateapj-landscape-table-arxiv/

Comment: I have questions about does your code really works out: I have trouble to get the error free compilation --- there are two parts. starting from "\turnpage = ..." and "\appdef \turnpage { ...."  What are needed overall?

Comment: @wonderich I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question. But to get the behaviour you asked, you need to use the whole of the *last* block of code I posted. You should **not** use the `\turnpage=...` block of code; that's output, not code. Also, use that code in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`).

Comment: @wonderich If my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as the answer for this question.